Installation error with USB boot
I am very new to these areas. I am currently using ubuntu 23.10 on my desktop PC, but I also need ubuntu 20.04 to use some software. I want to dual boot with different versions of ubuntu, but the installation is not working. ubuntu20.04 does not seem to recognize the internal SSD or HDD when booted via USB boot. Is there something I am missing?
Best regards.

If system is newer then 20.04, then you may not have needed drivers or older kernel will not support that new of hardware.  What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Is current install encrypted?
